# xCode changed size of views (in storyboard) after opening

Tags: ios, storyboard, size, xcode6, frame

After opening storyboard, xCode changed size of view by itself
 it look like this

[image]

Every time value is rise up. Does anybody know how fix it?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Yuri Solodkin checkout size of superView it must be bigger then size of subviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout size of superView it must be bigger then size of subviews. This bug was fixed in other xCode versions

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project and clean xcode cache. Are you using xcode6? It has some bugs especially on updating beta to stable version. And if these aren't your solution can you give more detail about 'Every time value is rise up' condition?

Cleaning Cache: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt project with new `Xcode` beta version
and then open in the current `Xcode` version.
Issue seems fixed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28875717/4296547